# The maximum distance in SO(3)

Tags: matrices

I wonder why $\max\Vert R_1-R_2 \Vert =2\sqrt2$, where $R_1,R_2 \in SO(3)$, $<A, B>=\operatorname{tr}(A^{\operatorname{T}}B)$.

Comment: A rotation matrix $R$ is a rotation around some axis passing through the origin in some angle $\theta$.  Its eigenvalues are $1, e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta}$.  So $\operatorname{tr}(R)=1+e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}=1+2\cos(\theta)$ which is between $-1$ and $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
\|R_1-R_2\|^2&=\operatorname{tr}((R_1-R_2)(R_1-R_2)^T)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(2I-R_1R_2^T-R_2R_1^T)\\
&=2(3-\operatorname{tr}(R_1R_2^T)).
\end{align*}
Think about the form of the rotation matrices (in terms of the angle of rotation [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)) and see if you can take if from here.